# syncing fork doesnt fetch all upstream branches

Tags: github

I forked a github repo some time back. Since then, some more branches have been added upstream.

But I see those new branches still not listed in the fork, even after I trigger 'Sync Fork', several times.

What is the right way of having all those branches in fork?